# Convergence of Euler Product for Leibniz Pi Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, dirichlet-series, euler-product

In class we were shown a derivation of Leibniz's formula for pi: 
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$
We can rewrite this formula using the following function on $\mathbb{N}$:
$$\chi(n)=
\begin{cases}1, &\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$}\\
-1,& \text{if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$}\\
0, & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$
Leibniz's Formula then becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(n)}{n}$$
We can rewrite this as an Euler product: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{1-\chi(p)/p}$$
I get how the formula was obtained, but I'm not sure why this product converges to $\pi/4$. When I look up proofs for Euler products of Dirichlet series, I get results that assume that the series absolutely converges (which I don't think is true for Leibniz's pi formula). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}}$ converges to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ for $\Re(s) \ge 1$, this is equivalent to the prime number theorem for this L-function : $\sum_{p \le x} \chi(p) = o(\frac{x}{(\log x)^k})$. The (generalized) Riemann hypothesis is $\sum_{p \le x} \chi(p) = \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2}(\log x)^2)$ so that the product would converge for $\Re(s) > 1/2$.

Comment: Are you asking about a proof of Leibniz's formula?